# Missing OpenAL32.dll After installing 2.79

Tags: installation

I had 2.76 which I was using an hour before downloading the installer for 2.7.9.0 11/09/2017
It seems to have deleted 2.76, but I still have 2.73 folders but no exe

When clicking the on desktop new icon the missing dll message comes up.

W10, Nvidia Quadro K2000

Don't know if I should find a Open32AL32.dll to download into the blender foundation/blender folder or do something else.

There are two exe - blender.exe and blednderplayer.exe

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried a clean uninstallation, and then a reinstall of 2.79a? That should provide you with all the files you need. If that still produces an error about a missing file, please file a bug report about this at https://developer.blender.org/

Answer (score 1):

Solved I have downloaded the .zip version of blender. Opening the folder I found an OpenAL32.dll Copy and pasted into the blenderfoundation/Blender folder (where the blender.exe file is) Now clicking the exe icon runs the program Only problem is that it doesn't know the user preferences or start file Found those in the old Blender version folder in Configs Copied and pasted UserPref and Startup to the config folder of new version All seems okay now